# jquery show more lines but not all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I searched on the Internet and there are many resources for show more/less button using different methods.

However, I do not want to show all the text immediately after clicking the read more button, I would like to show 5 more lines of the text instead.  So, whenever the user clicks the read more button, it shows 5 lines more.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var step = 5;
var initialheight = 2;
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentHeight = initialheight;
  var maxHeight = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0].scrollHeight / 12; // assuming 1em is 12px 
  $(".show-more a").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $content = $this.parent().prev("div.content");
    var linkText = $this.text();

    if (linkText.toUpperCase() === "SHOW MORE") {
      currentHeight += step;
      $content.css('height', currentHeight + 'em');
      if (currentHeight >= maxHeight - step) {
        linkText = "Show less";
      }

    } else {
      currentHeight -= step;
      $content.css('height', currentHeight + 'em');

      if (currentHeight <= step) {
        linkText = "Show more";
      }
    };

    $this.text(linkText);
  });
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Wpn94/1932/